# Thread Dependency Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a main class which spawns a thread, let's call them MainClass and MyThread.

```
public class MainClass extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   int sharedVariable;
   MyThread threadInstance;
   public MainClass (){
      sharedVariable = 2;
      threadInstance = new MyThread(this);
      threadInstance.run();
   }

  public int getSharedVariable(){ return sharedVariable; }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    //begin main class
 }
} 


public class MyThread implements Runnable {

     MainClass class;
     public MyThread(MainClass main_class){
         this.main_class= main_class;
      }

     @Override
     public run(){

     while(this.main_class is still active){

      //grab status of sharedVariable and wait for x amount of time.
      }
     }
    }
```

The problem is I do not know how to implement the while condition which checks if the MainClass instance is still alive and if it is, it has to use the this.main_class.getSharedVariable() to get the value of sharedVariable, then wait for x amount of time. MainClass has the main method .

Comment: `.run()` -> `.start()`. Also what do you mean by "*still active*"?

Comment: What do you mean by "alive" or "active"?

Comment: you can get the thread status by the getState() method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend holding onto the `Thread` instance and then calling `threadInstance.interrupt()` right before the `main(...)` method exits.

Something like:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
    try {
        ...
        // do main stuff here
        ...
    } finally {
        mainClass.threadInstance.interrupt();
    }
 }
```

Then in your thread you'd do:

```
 while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
     ...
 }
```

You'd also want to handle `InterruptedException` correctly:

```
 try {
     Thread.sleep(1000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // always a good pattern to re-interrupt the thread here
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     // if we are interrupted quit
     return;
 }
```

Btw, it is *very* bad form to leak the instance of an object during construction to another thread:

```
 new MyThread(this);
```

See here: [Why shouldn't I use Thread.start() in the constructor of my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834173/why-shouldnt-i-use-thread-start-in-the-constructor-of-my-class/11834276#11834276)

Also, you aren't starting a thread when you call `threadInstance.run();`.   You are just running it in the current thread.  You should use `threadInstance.start()` but not inside of the constructor like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CountDownLatch` which is very convenient for such tasks as waiting other threads to finish some activity (you can change `Thread.sleep(...)` argument in main to, say, 12000L and see what happens):

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class OtherThread extends Thread {
    private final CountDownLatch sharedLatch;

    OtherThread(CountDownLatch sharedLatch) {
        this.sharedLatch = sharedLatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean wokenByMain = false;
        try {
            wokenByMain = sharedLatch.await(10000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return; // or not return, whatever makes more sense in your case
        }
        System.out.println("heh: " + wokenByMain);
    }
}
class SOSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        OtherThread otherThread = new OtherThread(latch);
        otherThread.start();
        System.out.println("Scheduled other thread to be started");
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        System.out.println("going to release other thread");
        latch.countDown();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame implements Runnable {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    final Thread t=new Thread(new MainClass() {
            public void run(){
              //something
            });
    Thread t2=new Thread(new MyThread() {
            public void run() {
              while(t.isAlive) {
                //something
              }
            }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have formatted your code for you, but this answer would greatly benefit from some explanation as well.

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_