# Does happens before Program order rule work in constructors?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jls

Is it really possible to view partially constructed object in the thread created in the constructor because of the lack of synchronization and the leaking this instance?

Except for the case when there is a child class, of course, or we are doing implicit construction with clone or something like that - so let's suppose that the class is **final** and is it's fully initialized in the thread calling the constructor before calling other thread.

As I understand the following hb() rules apply,

- Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread
  that comes later in the program order (Program Order Rule)
- A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.
- If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then [hb(x, z)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3)

So does it mean that the following code is technically thread safe(I have taken it from the similar question [Why shouldn't I use Thread.start() in the constructor of my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834173/why-shouldnt-i-use-thread-start-in-the-constructor-of-my-class), there is also a similar question [Why it is bad practice to create a new thread on constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758690/why-it-is-bad-practice-to-create-a-new-thread-on-constructors), p.s. I hope *this* one won't be closed as duplicate)

```
final class SomeClass
{
    public ImportantData data = null;
    public Thread t = null;

    public SomeClass(ImportantData d)
    {
        t = new MyOperationThread();

        // t.start(); // Footnote 1

        data = d;

        t.start();    // Footnote 2
    }
}
```

P.S. obviously *data* field lacks encapsulation here, however this question is about the object's state visibility from thread t.

Comment: In practice you should be fine, in theory calling `this.data` in the thread's run method is undefined as `this` may not be initialised yet.

Comment: Your code example references footnotes. Where are they?

Comment: The footnotes are actually in the question I'm referring to. stackoverflow.com/questions/11834173/why-shouldnt-i-use-thread-start-in-the-constructor-of-my-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. The spec clearly [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts.

Of course, an object is not guaranteed to be fully initialized when a constructor completes, because constructors can invoke other constructors - either through an [explicit constructor invocation statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1), or because a superclass default constructor is implicitly called. Therefore, leaking `this` from a constructor is rather fragile - with a single or multiple threads.