# Java Memory Model and final fields

Tags: java, multithreading

I recently got confused when i referred to JMM for guarantees associated with "final". Here is an excerpt and example from JMM

Figure 4 gives an example that demonstrates how ﬁnal ﬁelds compare to normal ﬁelds. The class
FinalFieldExample has a ﬁnal int ﬁeld x and a non-ﬁnal int ﬁeld y. One thread might execute the method writer(), and another might execute the method reader(). Because writer() writes f
after the object’s constructor ﬁnishes, the reader() will be guaranteed to see the properly initialized value for f.x: it will read the value 3. However, f.y is not ﬁnal; the reader() method is therefore not guaranteed to see the value 4 for it

```
class FinalFieldExample {
    final int x;
    int y;
    static FinalFieldExample f;

    public FinalFieldExample() {
      x = 3;
      y = 4;
    }

    static void writer() {
      f = new FinalFieldExample();
    }

    static void reader() {
      if (f != null) {
        int i = f.x; // guaranteed to see 3
        int j = f.y; // could see 0
      }
    }
}
```

My confusion is that is an object 'Obj' has final and non-final fields is fully initialized and is being referenced by a Thread 'T', T will only see correct values for final fields ? What about non-final fields that are not mutated after construction. I understand that if they are mutated after construction thread 'T' might not see new value ( unless the field is a volatile ). But i am what if the field is non-final and non-volatile and is not mutated after construction ?

How does JVM implements guarantees associated with 'final' ? E.g for volatile there are memory barriers.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301061/is-this-a-safe-publication-of-object/10301179#10301179

Comment: there's a bug in this code - after the `if(f!=null)` check, `f` could appear to be null again. the code should use a local variable to cache `f`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15342485/2031799 - this is how final fields are implemented. In theory this example might break, but not in practice.

Answer (score 7):

This is addressed in this answer:

> [Is this a safe publication of object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301061/is-this-a-safe-publication-of-object/10301179#10301179)

To quote:

> The issue revolves around optimizations and reordering of instructions. When you have two threads that are using a constructed object without synchronization, it may happen that the compiler decides to reorder instructions for efficiency sake and allocate the memory space for an object and store its reference in the item field before it finishes with the constructor and the field initialization. Or it can reorder the memory synchronization so that other threads perceive it that way.

If you mark a field as final it forces the compiler to complete initialization for that field before the constructor completes.  Non-final fields have no such guarantees.

This is part of the [Java language definition (17.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).  Details about `final` fields are also in the [JLS (17.5)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).

More specifically, the `writer()` method constructs an instance of `FinalFieldExample` and stores in in a `static` field for other threads to consume.  Because of instruction reordering, the `y` field may not have been initialized yet.  If the *same thread* calls the `reader()` it will see `y` as `4` but other threads could see it as `0` because `f` was set and consumed possibly *before* `y` gets initialized and published.

To make this code correct, you must make `f` be `volatile` as well.

Comment: Gray. Thanks for reply. While compiler reordering instructions ( ByteCode instructions, not program instructions ) explains why f.y will not return 4. The JMM says : "Because writer() writes f after the object’s constructor ﬁnishes". So to me it seems that specification is ruling out such reordering.

Comment: Added more details @snegi.  The constructor could finish, the `f` field set, other threads could read `f.y`, and _then_ it could be initialized.  Or the initialization may not have been published.

Comment: But if contructor is finished f.y field is already assigned a value, right ?

Comment: No.  That's the point of the instruction reordering @snegi.  Non-final fields can be assigned _after_ the constructor finishes.

Comment: Thanks again Gray. I understand instruction reordering in other contexts, but wasnt aware of this non-final behavior. Any idea what is the reason behind this behavior ? I mean i am trying to think what optimization is achieved this way.

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned that to make the code correct we need to make f volatile as well. While i do understand volatile read semantics. But in this case, are you saying that if 'f' is volatile then constructor would not finish until all non-final fields are also initialized ?

Comment: @snegi if `f` is volatile, the write to `y` cannot be reordered after the write to `f`

Comment: zhong is right @snegi.  The `volatile` imposes a happens-before relationship and ensures memory synchronization.  The constructor must finish before `f` can be published.

Comment: Compiler reordering is one of the major optimizations available to the JVM.  I'm not 100% sure why it was specifically chosen but optimization is definitely the reason @snegi.

Comment: Huh?  I don't get your comment @RobinGreen.  My answer explains and shows references to the JLS around `final` field handling.  It is about instruction reordering.  Specifically how do you think I'm contradicting the JMM because I'm not.

Comment: @Gray sorry, I misread your answer

Comment: I've edited my answer in case you want to withdraw your downvote @RobinGreen.

Answer (score 3):

> How does JVM implements guarantees associated with 'final' ? E.g for volatile there are memory barriers.

To honor the semantics of `final` fields, some reordering cannot be done, and some memory barriers may be needed (on some processors). see http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

This means `final` is not free lunch. Take that into consideration before we use `final` everywhere. (Just because it's in Joshua's book doesn't mean it is correct)

Answer (score 1):

> My confusion is that is an object 'Obj' has final and non-final fields is fully initialized and is being referenced by a Thread 'T', T will only see correct values for final fields?

All threads are *guaranteed* to see correct values for `final` fields. This says nothing about non-final fields.

> What about non-final fields that are not mutated after construction.

The `final` modifier applies only to a specific field. You may "get lucky" with other non-final fields, but the guarantee applies *only* to the fields marked as `final`.

The fact that a non-final field is set in the constructor and not modified later is irrelevant.

Comment: In der practice it seems to be sufficient to have at least one final field in the class to make all the other fields visible. StoreStore barrier synchronized everything and JIT compiler does not reorder code over the constructor borders. It is definitely NOT a good idea to rely on this behavior.